# What is an antonym of "dreamy eyes"?

Tags: antonyms

Is there a common expression similar to "dreamy eyes" for a person looking at things with an eye of suspicion or jaded indifference?

Edit:

I think I misheard a movie scene. It was probably "dreamy-eyed", not "dreamy eyes". Meaning innocence, hopeful or rosy view of future, longing for a person, etc.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'dreamy eyes'.

Comment: "Dreamy eyes" suggests someon who is not paying attention. They are daydreaming. So "suspicion" or "jaded indifference" are not antonyms. Those also mean very different things. So 1) what meaning do you want - the opposite to "dreamy", the meaning of "suspicious" or the meaning or "jaded".  2)  What is wrong with using "suspicious" or "jaded" - "He looked at her with jaded indifference".  3) Why do you suppose English has this word?  Does it exist in your language?

Comment: @JamesK I  assumed "dreamy" meant a state of innocence, hopeful look toward future, longing, etc. So I was looking for an expression that had reference to "eyes" but with opposite meaning.

Comment: That's not what "dreamy eyes" mean.  Are you Japanese? This use of "dream" is very common in Japanese English (or so it seems to me)

Comment: @JamesK  I see some uses of "dreamy-eyed"  and "starry-eyed" in the sense I imagined for "dreamy eyes".

Comment: @Maesumi Unfortunately, those are expressions and not equivalent. In other words, “dreamy eyes” is not a variation of “dreamy-eyed,” but rather a completely different idiomatic term. First of all, the former is a noun, and the latter is an adjective….

While I understand the potential confusion, many expressions in English serve as exceptions to general rules on turning nouns into adjectives, etc. The sense you imagined is not correct, and the meaning is not equivalent.

Comment: @Maesumi And if you have doubts about the meaning of the word “dreamy,” I would encourage you to directly look it up in a dictionary rather than try to assume its meaning. Cambridge tells me it can mean 1) “seeming to be in a dream and not paying attention to what is happening around you” or 2) “very pleasant or attractive.”

Comment: @AnnabethYeung  I think my error started with mishearing a dialogue in a movie.  Time for a hearing aid I guess!

Comment: @Maesumi Since you misheard the dialogue, do you still have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re looking for a direct antonym for “dreamy eyes” in a context such as

> She looked at his picture with **dreamy eyes.**

You won’t find one. Not to mention that usually, “dreamy eyes” refers to someone who appears to be daydreaming, and not necessarily in a good or bad way. It doesn’t really function as an adverb. I believe you wish to express more of the idea of

> She looked at his picture **dreamily**.

In this case, you could directly use words like “suspiciously” in place of “dreamily.”